# Webpack error when running "webpack" command

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am getting the following error:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
```

when I run "webpack" in the terminal

my webpack config js file is as follow:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js?$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'react-hot!babel'
        }]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js']
    },
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist',
        hot: true
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ]
};
```

and my package.json as follow:

```
{
  "name": "hwr",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015",
      "react"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.11.4",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.11.1",
    "react-hot-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "history": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^15.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.6.1"
  }
}
```

Where does that error comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an error, you enabled the Hot Module Replacement (hence the [HMR]) feature in your Webpack build. That's just one of the log messages that come from the HMR feature. Sounds like you don't want to turn HMR on? In that case, you should remove `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080', 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'` entries from your entry points, the `react-hot` loader and in your loaders entry, the `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` from plugins and `hot: true` from your dev server settings.